# Name for removing all leaves on a graph to leave only cycles

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for the process of iteratively removing all leaves from a graph?

Comment: If you remove the leaves, you usually get new leaves... unless the graph is infinite.

Comment: @DonThousand If the tree ends up as a empty graph, that is fine. Any graph containing a cycle will survive the process. It feels like it should be called trimming.

Comment: I suggest "defoliation". (I do not know if this term has been used in graph theory)

Comment: This is called *pruning":  "removing a vertex of degree 1..."  https://books.google.com/books?id=cmcMae0jf1kC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22graph+theory%22+pruning+non-cycles&source=bl&ots=Va-2OFYftq&sig=ACfU3U2--N8_dfJeC4NRBVCMiVjPRCiLww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj458TL_ojnAhWEX80KHYM5DFsQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22graph%20theory%22%20pruning%20non-cycles&f=false

Comment: Isn't this the better algorithm to detect whether a graph has cycles, than doing a DFS from every node? The latter is usually the classical suggestion for cycle-detection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as finding the [*$2$-core*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)#k-Cores) of a graph. In general, the $k$-core of a graph is the subgraph obtained by, iteratively, deleting all vertices with degree less than $k$.

Sometimes (as Wikipedia does) we require the $k$-core to be connected, in which case there may be multiple $2$-cores, one for each connected component of the graph.

Comment: @DonThousand The term "[leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Tree)" is commonly used to refer a vertex of degree 1 in an undirected graph.

Comment: @DonThousand Graph theory terminology is as all-over-the-place as it gets, of course, but I've never seen "leaf" used for directed graphs before. Do you have examples of this usage? (Asking non-confrontationally.)

Comment: My apologies. I've only ever seen leaves in directed graphs as nodes with no children. It's used a lot in computational graph theory.

Comment: If that's the definition, then the notion of $k$-core probably extends to directed graphs in the same way (or in the reversed-arrow version of that), since the "directed degeneracy" you get this way might be just as useful for doing induction.